# Custom link instead of profile.php?username=test

Tags: php

I would appreciate some help with PHP.

I want to show my profile linking like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/SB0.3/test
```

Instead of the current:

```
http://localhost:8888/SB0.3/profile.php?username=test
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php 

if($general->logged_in()){?>
    <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php?username=<?php echo $user['username'];?>">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="change-password.php">Change password</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
<?php
}else{?>
    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Attempt something first before dumping your code and asking us to do your work. If you get stuck with your attempts, **then** ask for help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I've been trying and a friend told me to ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .htaccess to acomplish that.
Something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Sorry, didn't have the time to test it.
There's plenty of tutorials about .htaccess pretty url. Here's a good tutorial: 
http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls